# speech recognizer not working with my form I think they're not connected

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

hey I am using speech recognizer it doesn't recognize words in my project I mean he recognize them alone but he doesn't apply that on my form here is the code

```
 private void Speak_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      sr= new SpeechRecognizer();

        sr.SpeechRecognized += sr_SpeechRecognized;

    }
```

and the speechrecognized function :

```
void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Result.Text.ToString() + " ");
    }
```

I put a break point on the richtextbox1... line but he doesn't enter that function at all although he I can see he recognizes some words but doesn't enter the function it's like it's not connected to my form at all and when I go to google for example and say few words he recognizes them perfectly.
[image]

note: in the form itjust recognize commands he doesn't recognize words and I don't know why it's like it doesn't see the richtextbox in my form

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `SpeechRecognizer`, make sure that the focus is on your RichTextBox, otherwise it won't work. If the focus is on another control, it will put the words there. To avoid that, use a `SpeechRecognitionEngine`:

```
// make sure to set the type of `sr` to SpeechRecognitionEngine
private void Speak_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sr = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    sr.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar()); // load a dictation grammar, to allow dictation (recognizing all words)
    sr.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    sr.SpeechRecognized += sr_SpeechRecognized;
    sr.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // start recognizing
}

void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Result.Text.ToString() + " ");
}
```

The `SpeechRecognitionEngine` needs some more function calls before you can use it, but now it will always append text to your RichTextBox.